# WordPress custom Contact Form in Bootstrap modal is not showing validation & submission response

Tags: php, wordpress, modal-dialog, bootstrap-4, contact-form

For my WordPress (v5.5.1) I am using Bootstrap and built a Custom Contact Form in Bootstrap Modal with below HTML (followed this tutorial: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-build-your-own-wordpress-contact-form-and-why/).

```
<form id="contact-form" action="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>" method="post">

<div class="modal-body">
    <?php echo $response; ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control my-2" type="text" name="message_name" size="50" placeholder="Your full name" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_name']); ?>">
        <input class="form-control my-2" type="email" name="message_email" size="50" placeholder="Email address" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_email']); ?>">
        <input class="form-control my-2" type="tel" name="message_tel" size="50" placeholder="Country code, Phone number" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_tel']); ?>">
        <textarea class="form-control my-2" name="message_text" rows="2" placeholder="Your message" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_text']); ?>"></textarea>
        <input  class="form-control my-2" type="text" name="message_human" placeholder="Human check: Enter 2">
        <input type="hidden" name="message_url" value="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="message_page" value="<?php the_title(); ?>">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
    <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-search form-control">Send Enquiry</button>
</div>
```

Below the function to validate the Forms & show responses while Form submission:

```
function validateform() {
//response generation function
$response = "";

//function to generate response
function contact_g_form_response($type, $message) {

global $response;

if ($type == "success") {
    $response = "<div class='message-success text-center'>{$message}</div>";
} else {
    $response = "<div class='message-error text-center'>{$message}</div>";
}
}

//response messages
$not_human = "Enter current year in numbers.";
$missing_content = "Missing something.";
$email_invalid = "Check your Email address.";
$message_unsent = "Message was not sent. Try Again.";
$message_sent = "Thanks! We got your enquiry.";

//user posted variables
$name = $_POST['message_name'];
$email = $_POST['message_email'];
$fromEmail = $name . '<' . $email . '>';
$tel = $_POST['message_tel'];
$text = $_POST['message_text'];
$url = $_POST['message_url'];
$page = $_POST['message_page'];
$human = $_POST['message_human'];


//php mailer variables
$to = get_option('admin_email');
$subject = '[General Enquiry] ' . $name . ' | Phone Number:' . $tel;
$headers = 'From: ' . $fromEmail . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";

$message = '<html><body><h1>New general enquiry from ' . $name . '!</h1>'
    . '<p>Email: ' . $email . '</p>'
    . '<p>Phone Number: ' . $tel . '</P>'
    . '<p>Inquiry: ' . $text . '</P>'
    . '<p>From page: <b>' . $page . '</b></P>'
    . '<p>Page URL: ' . $url . '</p>'
    . '</body></html>';

if (!$human == 0) {
if ($human != 2) {
    contact_g_form_response("error", $not_human); //not human!
} else {

    //validate email
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        contact_g_form_response("error", $email_invalid);
    } else { //email is valid
        //validate presence of name, phone number
        if (empty($name) || empty($tel)) {
            contact_g_form_response("error", $missing_content);
        } else { //ready to go!
            $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers)); //mail to admin - striptags removing formatting
            // $sent2 = wp_mail($email, $subject, $body, $headers); //mail to visitor
            // if ($sent || $sent2) {
            if ($sent) {
                contact_g_form_response("success", $message_sent); //message sent!
            } else {
                contact_g_form_response("error", $message_unsent); //message wasn't sent
            }
        }
    }
}
} else if ($_POST['submitted']) {
contact_g_form_response("error", $missing_content);
}
}
```

In the earlier versions of WordPress the email was being sent without validation, with v5.5.1 upgrade, the Modal is closing without any validation and the email is also not being sent.

Answer (score 1):

You Just Need To replace this:

```
<form id="contact-form" action="<?php echo get_site_url();?>" method="post">
```

With This:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post">
```

Because You are displaying the error on the same page but on click of the submit button the action is taking you to a specific url and that's the reason the validations are not shown.

And This:

```
if ($type == "success") {
$response = "<div class='message-success text-center'>{$message}</div>";
} else {
$response = "<div class='message-error text-center'>{$message}</div>";
}
```

With This also:

```
if ($type == "success") {
$response =  $message;
echo $response;
} else {
$response =  $message;
echo $response;
}
```

Comment: Tried that, still no validation shown. Not only on the modal, on a normal Static page also validations are not showing.

Comment: The validation are working; however the Modal Form is getting closed even with errors, I tried both  `data-backdrop="static"` and `$( "#contact-form" ).submit(function( event ) { event.preventDefault(); });` with no luck; and for Form on the static page, page is getting refreshed.

Comment: you can ask another question for  separate errors don't change the same question [chameleon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) either I will flag your question.

Comment: since it is logically connected I have extended the question. I would have thanked you, if you could have helped me with that. I believe there is no need to threaten to flag the question, as my above query is not totally irrelevant. Cheers!  _edited to correct Harshit name_